# Calculating sha-512 checksum in meteor.js

Tags: meteor

Is there a meteor package for sha512 checksum calculation?

If not is there easy way to access node.js crypto package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is running on the server, you can access the `crypto` package with `Npm.require('crypto')`. Here's a quick example:

```js
var crypto = Npm.require('crypto');
var text = 'hello world';
var key = 'abc123';

var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key);
hash.update(text);
console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
```